# Calculate resistance of an unknown resistor in a circuit

Tags: resistors, resistance

I am currently studying some old exams for the upcoming one and I got stuck on this question, I seem to get the right answer by eyeballing the circuit but I want to be able to calculate the value.

The question is as follows: Calculate the resistance of R2.

What I tried doing was to calculate the voltage in the middle using Kirchoff's current law but I do not know where to go from there.

[image]

Comment: Ohms law + KCL. What id the voltage across R1 (trick question)? What can you do to simplify the schematic?

Comment: Annoyingly, circuit lab won't work for me so I can't make a proper answer just yet. Either way, re-draw the circuit so it is more logical. You can then see which resistors are in series and parallel. You can then use this information to use KCL and Ohm's Law to solve

Comment: I assume those A1 A2 boxes are 'ideal' current meters ? In which their resistance is zero. Hence R1 is irrelevant and total current is "8m". Now this is divided between R2 & R3 in parallel, where R2 is passing "2m". Hence rest must be through R3 = (8-2) 6m. So voltage across R3 = 2K x 6m = 12 K.m. Which is the same across R2. Hence R2 = (12 K.m / 2m) = 6K

Comment: @Kripacharya As you have given the solution away, why have you put it as a comment? If you are going to answer, put it in the answer section. Also, as this is a  studying question (like a homework question) we would tend to explain *how* to get to the correct answer, rather than just give it away. This encourages the OP to solve for themselves so they can learn. Also, since when was K.m. a unit of voltage?

Comment: @MCG  why the unnecessary criticism ? I have explained the steps. The calculation itself is trivial. Also - "m" and "K" are not a units of anything electrical I am aware of, but if "m" represents current, and "K" represents resistance, then the unit "K.m" definitely represents voltage. Etc. etc.

Comment: @Kripacharya it wasnt criticism really. You answered the question. So it should be an answer instead of a comment. And I was only explaining how people here *usually* deal with homework or study questions. Yes, the math is trivial to some, but to people studying, it may not be. Hence the practise of guiding people towards an answer, rather than giving it away. None of that was a criticism. If there was any, it was the units you used. Just use V for volts and A or mA for current. Makes it easier to understand.

Comment: Once again,  K and m are units used by OP,  not me.

Comment: @Kripacharya no, those units weren't used by OP. The simulator gives m to show the current is in mA. The ammeters have A to show it is measuring amperes and the m is to show it's in the mA range. The k is used for the resistors. OP answer their own question and used mA and V. The fact k and m were used to represent current and resistance doesn't mean K.m can be used as voltage. Its confusing and just wrong. If you think it's ok, keep using it and see how many people call you out on it. If someone asked what the voltage is over a resistor of 10ohms passing 1A, would you tell them its 10ohmA?

Comment: @MCG actually unit,or dimension analysis is an important tool in science n engineering. Btw it's not ohmA, it's ohm.A which IS volts.

Comment: @Kripacharya just use the correct units. And don't get snappy and assume someone is being critical. The simple thing is you should have written an answer, not a comment. And you should have used the correct units. End of discussion.

Comment: Why didn't you say so?  In that case, please replace Ohm by Kg.m^2/(s^3.I^2)

Comment: Just trying to value-add dude. Why ARE you so upset about that ???

Answer (score 2):

I seem to have gotten the right answer now, what I did was that I used KCL as follows:

8mA - 2mA(From the unknown resistor) - ( 0 - Vu / R3) = 0

I then moved the equation around as following:

-8mA + 2mA = Vu * ( - 1/R3)

Then:

-6mA / (- 1/R3) = Vu = 12 V

hen, by using Ohm's law I calculated the resistance:

R = V / I = 12 / 2mA = 6000 Ohm's